# Developing Apps for Cydia

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak, cydia

i am interested in how to develop Apps and Programs for Jailbroken Devices or Cydia,
what API's do i have to involve in Xcode?
Could please somebody help me with that?

thanks

Comment: Its still the same APIs, except without any review process you are free to use all the undocumented and private APIs. For that sort of information you need to investigate or look around for other sites where those things are discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications distributed in Cydia are developed using the same process as those in the AppStore, only they are not subject to its restrictions. You can export IPAs via Xcode without code-signing them.

If you are talking about making tweaks that modify the behavior of stock iOS apps (such as Safari or the Springboard) you need to get more information about [mobile substrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) and [theos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started)

Do not hesitate if you need further information

Comment: Heyho i found something what is called iosopendev ... is that right?
i acctually have an apple dev account and i am interested to develop for cydia too, but can i run my "normal" app with xcode on my devices too if its jailbroken and if iosopendev is installed?
here is the link:http://iosopendev.com/download/
please help, thanks :)

Comment: You don't need iOSOpenDev to run your normal app on your jailbroken iOS device. But if you want to create apps/tweaks specifically for jailbroken devices, iOSOpenDev looks good and won't interfere with your AppStore app creation & debugging process.

Comment: Hey man thank you so much :)
i'll just have to wait for the ios 6 iPhone 4s JB :/ but thx!